# From list to sentence on python3

Tags: string, python-3.x

my mind,from:

```
>>>text='hi how are you'
>>>example=text.split()
>>>print(example[0:4:2])
```

it would print a list

`['hi', 'are']`

my question, how to convert them?
from list like above, to:

`>>>
hi are`

if you got it, please answer.

Comment: `' '.join(example)`? But that will only get you back to what you started with if the starting whitespace was consistent.

Comment: (or about 900 other questions...)

Comment: isn't work. it just print letters

Comment: What do you mean *"it just print letters"*? Try `print(' '.join(['hi', 'are']))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
text='hi how are you'
example=text.split()
print(' '.join(example[0:4:2]))
```